# Не получается создать шаблон для сайта HTML с двумя формами, которые будут принимать текстовые данные

Tags: html

Не получается создать шаблон для сайта HTML с двумя формами, которые будут принимать текстовые данные.

Есть-ли какие-то статьи по данному вопросу? Может это прописано где-то в документации?

Comment: А что конкретно не получается?

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть один из примеров одного моего проекта на Flask (в конце присутсвует синтаксис шаблонизатора jinja, если интересно - можете его удалить если он не нужен).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Заголовок</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/адрес1">Ссылка на внешний источник</a>
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    <form action="/адрес_формы1" method="post">
          <label>Описание поля ввода</label>
          <input type="text" name="имя1">
          <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>

    <form action="/адрес_формы2" method="post">
      <label>Описание поля ввода</label>
      <input type="text" name="имя2">
      <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>

      {%if available %}
        {{ available }}
      {%endif%}
  </body>
</html>
```